# Data corruption when taking gradient of numerical data in python

Tags: finite-difference, python

**Question**

Below is a plot of a graph $y$ and its derivative $dy/dx$ calculated using python's `numpy.gradient`which approximates the derivative with finite differences using a central scheme. Clearly there is a problem in that unphysical kinks have been introduced in the result.

Since differentiation will act to amplify any high frequency content in the original data, numerical differentiation is always tricky although here my data is relatively smooth and noise free. Does anyone recognise this type of behaviour and what can be done to get a proper derivative?

**Some info on the data:**

$y$ is data that is sampled from a computational mesh and has many more sample points for small $x$, getting coarser as $x$ increases. The data you see plotted is found by linearly interpolating on a uniform number of data points. However because of the non-uniform spacing I have had to use a large number of points so that the data points for small $x$ are effectively the "true" data values, but at high $x$ there are many points in between the "true" ones that are just linear interpolations, adding no real information to the graph. At first I thought maybe there is some floating point rounding problems that are causing

[image]

**EDIT: MCVE**

To illustrate the problem here is a small subset of the data to produce this figure:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Subset of data such that
# sub_data = data[50:150,:]

sub_data = np.asarray([[1.700089160294737667e-05, 9.632603526115417480e-01],
[1.733388671709690243e-05, 9.813255667686462402e-01],
[1.766688365023583174e-05, 9.993913173675537109e-01],
[1.799987876438535750e-05, 1.017457604408264160e+00],
[1.833267015172168612e-05, 1.035513401031494141e+00],
[1.866566708486061543e-05, 1.053580760955810547e+00],
[1.899866219901014119e-05, 1.071648478507995605e+00],
[1.933165913214907050e-05, 1.089716911315917969e+00],
[1.966444870049599558e-05, 1.107774615287780762e+00],
[2.000245694944169372e-05, 1.126114964485168457e+00],
[2.033545388258062303e-05, 1.144184470176696777e+00],
[2.066844899673014879e-05, 1.162254691123962402e+00],
[2.100123856507707387e-05, 1.180314183235168457e+00],
[2.133423549821600318e-05, 1.198385119438171387e+00],
[2.166586818930227309e-05, 1.216382265090942383e+00],
[2.199886512244120240e-05, 1.234277606010437012e+00],
[2.233165650977753103e-05, 1.251089692115783691e+00],
[2.266465162392705679e-05, 1.267913579940795898e+00],
[2.299764855706598610e-05, 1.284739017486572266e+00],
[2.333043812541291118e-05, 1.301555633544921875e+00],
[2.366844637435860932e-05, 1.318636536598205566e+00],
[2.400144148850813508e-05, 1.335466384887695312e+00],
[2.433443842164706439e-05, 1.352297544479370117e+00],
[2.466722798999398947e-05, 1.369119763374328613e+00],
[2.500022492313291878e-05, 1.385953545570373535e+00],
[2.533322003728244454e-05, 1.402788400650024414e+00],
[2.566621697042137384e-05, 1.419624686241149902e+00],
[2.599900835775770247e-05, 1.436451792716979980e+00],
[2.633200347190722823e-05, 1.453290104866027832e+00],
[2.666500040504615754e-05, 1.470129728317260742e+00],
[2.699799551919568330e-05, 1.486970305442810059e+00],
[2.733579822233878076e-05, 1.504054188728332520e+00],
[2.766743091342505068e-05, 1.520827651023864746e+00],
[2.800042602757457644e-05, 1.537671327590942383e+00],
[2.833321741491090506e-05, 1.554505705833435059e+00],
[2.866621252906043082e-05, 1.571351289749145508e+00],
[2.899920946219936013e-05, 1.588197588920593262e+00],
[2.933220639533828944e-05, 1.605044960975646973e+00],
[2.966499596368521452e-05, 1.621882915496826172e+00],
[2.999799289682414383e-05, 1.638731956481933594e+00],
[3.033098801097366959e-05, 1.655581831932067871e+00],
[3.066398494411259890e-05, 1.672432422637939453e+00],
[3.100178582826629281e-05, 1.689526319503784180e+00],
[3.133478094241581857e-05, 1.706378579139709473e+00],
[3.166777969454415143e-05, 1.723231554031372070e+00],
[3.200077480869367719e-05, 1.740085244178771973e+00],
[3.233356619603000581e-05, 1.756929397583007812e+00],
[3.266656131017953157e-05, 1.773784637451171875e+00],
[3.299955642432905734e-05, 1.790640354156494141e+00],
[3.333234781166538596e-05, 1.806897401809692383e+00],
[3.366534292581491172e-05, 1.822490572929382324e+00],
[3.399697743589058518e-05, 1.838021636009216309e+00],
[3.433498568483628333e-05, 1.853852272033691406e+00],
[3.466777343419380486e-05, 1.869441509246826172e+00],
[3.500077218632213771e-05, 1.885041832923889160e+00],
[3.533376730047166348e-05, 1.900644183158874512e+00],
[3.566676605259999633e-05, 1.916247844696044922e+00],
[3.599955380195751786e-05, 1.931843996047973633e+00],
[3.633255255408585072e-05, 1.947450876235961914e+00],
[3.666554766823537648e-05, 1.963059425354003906e+00],
[3.699854278238490224e-05, 1.978669643402099609e+00],
[3.733133416972123086e-05, 1.994271874427795410e+00],
[3.766432928387075663e-05, 2.009885072708129883e+00],
[3.800233753281645477e-05, 2.025733470916748047e+00],
[3.833533264696598053e-05, 2.041349411010742188e+00],
[3.866812403430230916e-05, 2.056957483291625977e+00],
[3.900111914845183492e-05, 2.072576045989990234e+00],
[3.933411426260136068e-05, 2.088196039199829102e+00],
[3.966690564993768930e-05, 2.103807926177978516e+00],
[3.999854016001336277e-05, 2.119366645812988281e+00],
[4.033153527416288853e-05, 2.134990215301513672e+00],
[4.066453038831241429e-05, 2.150615453720092773e+00],
[4.099732177564874291e-05, 2.166232347488403320e+00],
[4.133032052777707577e-05, 2.181859731674194336e+00],
[4.166832513874396682e-05, 2.197722673416137695e+00],
[4.200132389087229967e-05, 2.213352441787719727e+00],
[4.233411164022982121e-05, 2.228973865509033203e+00],
[4.266711039235815406e-05, 2.244606018066406250e+00],
[4.300010550650767982e-05, 2.260239124298095703e+00],
[4.333310062065720558e-05, 2.275873422622680664e+00],
[4.366589200799353421e-05, 2.291499376296997070e+00],
[4.399888712214305997e-05, 2.307135581970214844e+00],
[4.433188223629258573e-05, 2.322772979736328125e+00],
[4.466467362362891436e-05, 2.338401794433593750e+00],
[4.499766873777844012e-05, 2.352876663208007812e+00],
[4.533567698672413826e-05, 2.367459297180175781e+00],
[4.566867210087366402e-05, 2.381829023361206055e+00],
[4.600146712618879974e-05, 2.396192073822021484e+00],
[4.633309799828566611e-05, 2.410506963729858398e+00],
[4.666609311243519187e-05, 2.424882888793945312e+00],
[4.699908822658471763e-05, 2.439260959625244141e+00],
[4.733187961392104626e-05, 2.453632116317749023e+00],
[4.766487472807057202e-05, 2.468014001846313477e+00],
[4.799787348019890487e-05, 2.482398033142089844e+00],
[4.833086859434843063e-05, 2.496783494949340820e+00],
[4.866365998168475926e-05, 2.511162519454956055e+00],
[4.900166459265165031e-05, 2.525767564773559570e+00],
[4.933466334477998316e-05, 2.540158748626708984e+00],
[4.966766209690831602e-05, 2.554551839828491211e+00],
[5.000044984626583755e-05, 2.568938016891479492e+00]])


x = sub_data[:,0]
y = sub_data[:,1]
dx = x[1]-x[0]

dydx = np.gradient(y,dx)

plt.figure()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(x,y,'k-')
ax2.plot(x,dydx, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The jaggedness in that first derivative, when looking at the plot for $Y$, isn't something I would expect. Have you tried computing a numerical derivative yourself and seeing what you get?

Comment: @choward I have tried using the simplest thing I could think of which is forward differencing (calculating the difference array of `y` and dividing it by the difference array of `x`) but the result is still the same! Im thinking the problem is in my data and the fact that I have so many closely sampled points...?

Comment: @Jack You could fit your data $y(x)$ with a differentiable function (e.g., a polynomial) in order to find a better estimate of the derivative. Scipy's [`scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy-interpolate-univariatespline) provides such a fit and has a convenient built in `derivative()` method

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Stelios I actually tried that already, but that spline returns all NaNs (I have also removed any possible duplicate points already)

Comment: @Kirill I will try to reproduce it with data that is smaller and can therefore by copied and pasted into the question.

Comment: @Jack what is the smallest $x$ difference for the really refined part of your data set? If it is too small, it could cause issues due to finite precision. I would recommend coarsening your data in the really refined area and seeing what you get.

Comment: @Kirill I now have edited a MCVE. Thank you.

Comment: Apart from the small bumps, your small subset looks like *exactly what I'd expect to be the correct result* on data that has been linearly interpolated.

Comment: @immibis is that because of the kinks near each joining of the linear interpolate?

Comment: @Jack The derivative would be constant over each linear interpolate and step between them, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $x$-coordinates of your data points are not equally spaced (`x[1:]-x[:-1]` is not constant), so `numpy.gradient` is not applicable because it assumes that the data is equally spaced (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html). 
Even just forward differences on their own would be better than using an inaccurate value of $\Delta x$ in centered differences.

With forward differences, the small bumps disappear, but the discontinuities remain, so those probably come from the data itself. You can smooth them by constructing a spline interpolant (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

Comment: Darn! Sadly I knew this but I had assumed that due to the way I had acquired the data the points were equally spaced...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plot of the derivative evaluated by first performing an spline fit of the data. Compared to the finite difference approach, the result appears more natural.

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

spl = UnivariateSpline(sub_data[:,0],sub_data[:,1])

x_range = np.linspace(sub_data[0,0], sub_data[-1,0],1000)
plt.plot(x_range,spl.derivative(1)(x_range),'b', label = 'spline')
plt.plot(x,dydx, 'r-', label = 'finite diff.')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I had originally used splev without success for some reason but this worked nicely on my full data although I had to play around with the smoothing factor a bit!